# How do I move my IK bone without deforming the mesh

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

[image]
[image]

Whenever I move my IK foot bones if deforms like this. I've been trying to teach myself rigging. I have done IK rigging before but I never had this problem before. can anyone help me fix this? Thanks!

Edit: Yes, I did try unchecking the deform box but it still deforms in a weird way

Comment: you probably made those bones 1st and then made weight paint right? You should create those bones after you make your weight paints

Comment: I applied automatic weights

Comment: that's weight painting as well (only automatic version), did you create those bones before weights or after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before parenting you need to disable the *Deform* option for all the IK's *Target* or *Pole Target* bones (i.e. the bones that control your IK bone). So disable this option. Now, all these vertices won't be moved by these bones anymore, but they are still part of the vertex groups that were created when parenting, so your mesh won't work fine yet, you either need to parent again, or give the corrections in *Weight Paint* mode so that all these areas are now influenced by the good bones.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did try unchecking the Deform box but it still deforms in a weird way

Comment: yes because these vertices are affected to the vertex groups that were linked to these bones, not to any other bones, now you need to either reparent With Automatic Weight or assign these vertices to the other vertex groups (foot groups probably)

Comment: Hey! It worked! Thank you so much